# Is there a way to turn off the Caption on a TDBRadioGroup

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a `TDBRadioGroup` that I've added to my form.

I'd really like to have the caption to the left of it instead of on top (the form's a little busy and tall, and I'm trying to squeeze it in).

I can add my own label to the left of the Radio Group. But the control insists on reserving space of a Caption that does not exists. Is there a way I can turn it off completely?

The best we've come up with so far is sticking it on a `TPanel` and then hiding the top couple lines off-panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TGroupBox` (and it's descendant `TDBGroupBox`) are basically wrappers around the Windows [GroupBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#group_boxes). The control is designed to sport a user-defined label across the upper-left corner, and doesn't have any style setting to remove it.

So, short of creating your own control to host a series of `TRadioButton` controls yourself and display them, there's no built-in way to disable the space reserved for the caption. You can suppress the text, of course, by setting the `Caption := ''`, but the padding for the text descenders is not removed simply because the caption isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the paint procedure for TRadioGroup so that the frame is drawn closer to the top of your item list.  You could create a new component of type TNoCaptionRadioGroup.  You might still have to use the panel trick that you have tried, but by lowering the top of the frame you can grab the space consumed by the non-existent caption.  Something like this:

```
tNoCaptionRadioBox = class(TRadioGroup)
protected
procedure paint; override;
end;

procedure tNoCaptionRadioBox.paint;
var
H: Integer;
R: TRect;
begin
with Canvas do
begin
  Font := Self.Font;
  H := TextHeight('0');
  R := Rect(0, H, Width, Height);
  if Ctl3D then
  begin
    Inc(R.Left);
    Inc(R.Top);
    Brush.Color := clBtnHighlight;
    FrameRect(R);
    OffsetRect(R, -1, -1);
    Brush.Color := clBtnShadow;
  end else
    Brush.Color := clWindowFrame;
  FrameRect(R);
  end;
end;
```

This is taken from the code for painting a TCustomGroupBox.  I have removed the code for drawing the caption and have changed the top of the frame to the full height of the Font.  Your actual captioned radio buttons will still be drawn where Windows wants them to be and with the default spacing.

Remember to register the new component by running the package installation tool.

```
procedure Register;
begin
RegisterComponents('myComponents', [tNoCaptionRadioBox]);
end;
```